# PHP preg_replace() compilation failed: missing )

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following function to return a clean path for a script.

```
function cleanPath($path) {
        $path = (string) $path;
        $path = preg_replace(
            array(
            '#[\n\r\t\0]*#im',
            '#/(\.){1,}/#i',
            '#(\.){2,}#i',
            '#(\.){2,}#i',
            '#('.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'){2,}#i'
            ),
            array(
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '/'
            ),
            $path
            )
        ;
        return rtrim($path,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
```

PHP gives the error:

> **Warning**:  preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation
>    failed: missing ) at offset 7 in **C:\wamp\www\extlogin\app\ni\inc\classes\cfiletree.php** on line
>    **18**

Any ideas about what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is `\` which means it'll escape the `)` rather than match a backslash. You need to escape `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` so that it becomes `\\` in the regex.

The safest way to escape strings placed in regular expressions is to use `preg_quote`:

```
preg_quote(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '#');
```

The second argument, `'#'`, is the separator you use for your regular expression, which in your case is `#`.

Comment: Is there a way to catch that particular error, i.e. can you "test" a pattern before using it?