# PHP Warning: preg_replace(); compilation failed: missing ) at

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

this line of smarty_internal_templatebase.php:
`$output .= preg_replace('/(<%|%>|<\?php|<\?|\?>)/', "<?php echo '\$1'; ?>\n", $curr_split);`
is giving me the error: Compilation failed:missing ) at..

I think it has something to do with **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** ****
like here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142263/php-preg-replace-compilation-failed-missing](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
The error is strange becouse the script is core Presta/Smarty script, so I quess it shouldn't be wrong.

So how to modify that line ta avoid that error? Would appreciate any help,
Thank you

Shall I

`preg_quote(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '#');`

with

`preg_replace('/(<%|%>|<\?php|<\?|\?>)/', "<?php echo '\$1'; ?>\n", $curr_split)`

Answer (score 0):

OK - the Error was connected with Prestashop vulnerability discovered in 2022/07:

https://build.prestashop-project.org/news/2022/major-security-vulnerability-on-prestashop-websites/

> According to our conversations with shop owners and developers, the
> recurring modus operandi looks like this -
>
> 1. The attacker submits a POST request to the endpoint vulnerable to SQL injection.
> 2. After approximately one second, the attacker submits a GET request to the homepage, with no parameters. This results in a PHP file called
>    blm.php being created at the root of the shop’s directory.
> 3. The attacker now submits a GET request to the new file that was created, blm.php, allowing them to execute arbitrary instructions.
>
> After the attackers successfully gained control of a shop...

That attempt results (among others) in error like:

```
Compilation failed:missing ) at.
```